# How to dynamically connect Excel data sources to MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic, excel, vb

How to connect **Excel(2010)** with **Mapinfo(10.0)**? I saw that Excel can be connected using **Excel** as **Data Source** but my Data Source is already **MS-SQL**. Actually I would like to **reflect** any **changes** in excel to mapinfo and MS-SQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are your real data? In excel or ms-sql? MapInfo should be able to connect to both, but probably not to an excel-file linked to ms-sql.

Comment: My real data is in Excel but I store it in MS-SQL too. Actually the changes are implemented in Excel and then uploaded to MS-SQl using mapinfo.

Comment: You can link to the excel file from within MapInfo (see documentation). But you will have read-ony access and you are not allowed to have the xls file open in Excel at the same time.